# Qt: enterEvent and leaveEvent doesnt work

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt-creator, qwidget

I have strange problem with mouse events in Qt. I have following code:

```
#ifndef QSTONEFIELD_HPP_
#define QSTONEFIELD_HPP_

#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>

class QStoneField : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    // some stuff

public:
    // some methods

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);   
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
    virtual void enterEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
    virtual void leaveEvent(QMouseEvent * event);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif
```

And in second file I have:

```
#include "qstonefield.hpp"
// FIXME temporary include
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// some other methods ..

void QStoneField::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    cout << "CLICK!" << endl << flush;
}

void QStoneField::enterEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    cout << "ENTER!" << endl << flush;
}

void QStoneField::leaveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    cout << "LEAVE!" << endl << flush;
}
```

And now when I compile and run it, I can invoke mousePressEvent because program prints "CLICK!", but when I am crossing the widget by mouse, it prints just nothing.
Of course in main.cpp I didnt forget to stone.setMouseTracking(true).

Why enterEvent and leaveEvent doesnt work? It should work according to documentation.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature of your function should be:

```
virtual void QStoneField::enterEvent(QEvent * event);
virtual void QStoneField::leaveEvent(QEvent * event);
```

You are simply using the wrong parameter for the function which means the one from Qwidget are not overwritten.

I recommend you to consider what the default implementation does, for example :

```
virtual void QStoneField::leaveEvent(QEvent * event){
       //do my own things
       QWidget::leaveEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: It perfectly works, thank you! Probably I have old documentation because there is QMouseEvent..

Comment: @Firzen If you used `override` then this would have been a compile-time error rather than unexpected runtime behaviour.

Comment: Looks like in current qt (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#enterEvent) it is needed to use `QEnterEvent`, not `QEvent`.